Why is the Hawtio UI empty (and also the Jolokia management endpoint response)?
I'm in the process of embedding Hawtio in my Camel Spring Boot application. I followed the Hawtio getting started guide to setup configuration, but something is wrong as the Hawtio UI is empty when I bring it up (no metrics). I added the following properties to application.properties:
spring.jmx.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,camelroutes,prometheus,hawtio,jolokia

And the following dependencies:
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
  <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-management-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-xml-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

Hawtio pulls data from the Jolokia management endpoint which returns this response:

{"request":{"type":"version"},"value":{"agent":"2.0.2","protocol":"7.3","details":{"agent_version":"2.0.2","agent_id":"192.168.0.115-49016-52f67539-servlet","server_product":"jetty","server_vendor":"Eclipse","server_version":"12.0.6","secured":false,"url":"http://192.168.0.115:8081/xxxxx/jolokia"},"id":"192.168.0.115-49016-52f67539-servlet","config":{"agentId":"192.168.0.115-49016-52f67539-servlet","allowErrorDetails":"false","includeStackTrace":"false"},"info":{"proxy":{},"jmx":{}}},"status":200,"timestamp":1715131260}

As you can see, the JMX object is empty, but why? I see all the MBeans in JConsole.
I do not see any errors or interesting messages in the log when pulling up the Hawtio UI:
2024-05-07T18:27:20.252-07:00 DEBUG 49016 --- [xxxxx] [  XNIO-1 task-2] 
io.hawt.web.auth.LoginRedirectFilter     : Check if path [/xxxxx/hawtio/index.html] 
requires redirect

2024-05-07T18:27:20.252-07:00 DEBUG 49016 --- [xxxxx] [  XNIO-1 task-2] 
io.hawt.web.filters.BaseTagHrefFilter    : baseTagHref = /xxxxx/hawtio

2024-05-07T18:27:20.274-07:00 DEBUG 49016 --- [xxxxx] [  XNIO-1 task-2] 
io.hawt.web.auth.SessionExpiryFilter     : Accessing 
[/xxxxx/hawtio/static/js/main.d0c4c242.js], hawtio 

Or when I hit the Jolokia endpoint. Just this:
2024-05-07T18:23:50.315-07:00 DEBUG 49016 --- [xxxxx] [  XNIO-1 task-2] 
io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationFilter    : Handling request for path: /xxxxx/jolokia

2024-05-07T18:23:50.315-07:00 DEBUG 49016 --- [xxxxx] [  XNIO-1 task-2] 
io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationFilter    : No authentication needed for path: /xxxxx/jolokia

Everything looks ok, so what am I missing? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!
Camel version: 4.5
Hawtio: 4.0.0
Spring Boot: 3.2.3
Jolokia: 2.0.2

You can start by comparing your application with the working official Spring Boot example:
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/hawtio-4.0.0/examples/springboot
One checkpoint:

Have you added spring-boot-starter-actuator to the dependencies?
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>




I had the same problem. I analyzed my process and there is problem with JSLT and JSONATA activities.
If I remove the following node, everything works correctly.
    - to:
        id: to-e18f
        description: Merge data
        uri: jslt
        parameters:
          resourceUri: routes/merge-data.json

I believe it is the same problem as described here:
https://lists.apache.org/thread/11o9w0l234gtt3o8639w0hor805f1lxm
I look forward to 4.7.0 to confirm.
